# Wordpress plugin to search into post's attachments (typically text file like doc or Pdf)

Tags: wordpress, search, pdf, doc, attachment

I'm looking for a plugin to extend the search into the content of attachments (typically text file like doc or Pdf).

Comment: Removed my answer since the plugin I posted searches attachment names, but not inside the attachments...

Comment: I didn't see any PDF indexers in the plugin repository. This would be a good question to find an answer to, and an incredibly useful plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This topic](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/344254) in the WordPress support forums addresses this question, and suggests  [Google custom search](http://www.google.com/cse/), which should in theory search PDFs and DOCs and would be easy to set up and try, or the [Search Everything](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/) plugin, which might be what Jeff said doesn't work in his comment above.

There's also the [Sphider Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sphider/), an search plugin that claims to support indexing PDF and DOC files. It might be more difficult to set up, but it's the best option I can find.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same need (indexing contents of uploaded files) and was amazed there was no plugin that allows this. The above do not work, and searching gave nothing.

So - I wrote one.

It works, we're using it at work. It's not super friendly - takes a little bit of expertise to ensure java & dependency (apache tika) are working - but it does the trick.

I may update it & submit to wordpress plugins - but meanwhile, if it helps anyone:

http://avatari.net/public/wordpress/masala/

Comment: Is there a possibility to reindex already exiting pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Problem: Need to use wordpress search to find text within uploaded pdf files.

Solution:

Step 1. Upload your pdf(s)

Step 2. Under the description of each pdf paste the following:

Click the link above to view PDF

Step 3. Copy the text from the pdf and paste it in the above in place of PDFDOCUMENTTEXT

Step 4. Install [Search Everything](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/) plugin and then activate.
 Your searches should now return results including a list of attachment pages that include the text within the pdfs but will direct the user to click on the pdf link.

If anyone else knows of a better way to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution. Maybe it will work for you also :

Masala Plugin : https://github.com/nanodust/masala , which actually add new post meta field while uploading any doc/pdf/ppt/txt file. It will put the file content into newly created meta field

This plugin uses :
1) Java
2) Apache Tika – really awesome
3) Search Everything plugin which is responsible for search in meta table.

Here, you need to configure :
1) Java path
2) Download latest apache tika jar and you can put into your project root folder and configure path in masala.php
4) Give the allowed file extensions.

ITS DONE !!